# how to calculate a string of probabilties

Tags: probability

What is the formula for calculating the chance of something occurring when you have 2 or more probabilities.  For example, if my chance of winning poker hand #1 is 72% and the chance of winning poker hand #2 is 83% and the chance of winning poker hand #3 is 67%, how do I calculate the chance of losing all 3 hands.

Thanks for any insight.

TLA

Comment: do your three poker hands something common or are they completely independent?

Comment: Are the losses independent?

Comment: if the hands are drawn from the same game, they can't be independent

Comment: All three hands at the same time?
0.72 * 0.83 * 0.67 is the only probability that I could think of that makes sense in the context of playing 3 independent rounds.

Comment: @Inathan The probability $(1-0.72)(1-0.83)(1-0.67)$ not only makes sense too, but actually gives the correct answer under the assumption that the three outcomes are independent.  Note that the given chances are those of *winning* while the question asks for the chance of *losing*.

Comment: @whuber thanks for the correction. Of course you are right

Comment: Thanks for responses. I think whuber and Kodiologist got what I was looking for. I did mean 3 hands independent of each other. TLA

Answer (score 1):

When several events are independent, the probability of the intersection (i.e., the event that all of them occur) is just the product of their individual probabilities. (In fact, this is the usual definition of independence.) When they're dependent, on the other hand, the nature of the dependence influences the probability of the intersection. The probability of the intersection can be as low as 0 and as high as the probability of the least likely single event.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the relationship of the hands (are they dependent or independent).

I will give an example for independent events and you can make some conclusions. Imagine your chances of passing Maths, English and History tests are 0.72, 0.81 and 0.4, respectively. Imagine you take the tests in the same order. What is the chance for you to fail all three tests?

Solution: The probability of passing the English test is not influenced by passing/failing the Maths test (ignoring the condition you get tired after the Maths test). That is:
$$P(fail \  E| fail \ M \ or \ pass \ M)=P(fail \ E)=1-P(pass \ E)=1-0.81=0.19.$$
Similar explanation applies to passing/failing the History test.

> Now for independent events $A$ and $B$, the multiplication rule is:
>   $$P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B|A)=P(A)\cdot P(B).$$

Hence:
$$P(fail \ M \cap fail \ E \cap fail \ H)=P(fail \ M)\cdot P(fail \ E)\cdot P(fail \ H) =$$
$$0.28\cdot 0.19\cdot 0.6=0.03192.$$
The good news is your chance of failing all three tests is very low.